# Connect an Azure web role to an on-prem SQL server (Cisco VPN)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-virtual-network

Given that we have a Cisco VPN device on-prem, which Azure networking feature is most appropriate to use?

There's are SO many networking features in Azure and SO much out dated information on the internet, even here on SO, that I simply cannot figure out the best way to get my web role talking to an on-prem SQL server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your Cloud Service Web Role currently deployed in an Azure Virtual Network?  If so, site-to-site VPN or ExpressRoute would be the way to go.

Comment: Yes I would also recommend the site-to-site VPN.

Comment: We're going to give this a try tomorrow and see how it goes.